# How to access constant defined in child class from parent class functions?

Tags: php, oop, class

I saw this example from php.net:

```
<?php
class MyClass {

     const MY_CONST = "yonder";

     public function __construct() {

          $c = get_class( $this );
          echo $c::MY_CONST;
     }
}

class ChildClass extends MyClass {

     const MY_CONST = "bar";
}

$x = new ChildClass(); // prints 'bar'
$y = new MyClass(); // prints 'yonder'
?>
```

But $c::MY_CONST is only recognized in version 5.3.0 or later. The class I'm writing may be distributed a lot.

Basically, I have defined a constant in ChildClass and one of the functions in MyClass (father class) needs to use the constant. Any idea?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

How about using `static::MY_CONST`?

Comment: I do not get why people are getting to deep into OOP in other answers. Your solution is the only correct one and way simpler

Comment: There is something wrong about accessing a `const` by using the `static` keyword. Could you explain why that works? PHP Docs confused me in this as well. Thanks.

Comment: @checksum: no, thats wrong – `self::MY_CONST` prints in both cases "yonder" – constant defined in child. Question was "How to access constant defined in child class from parent class functions?".

Comment: I'm super glad this works but I'm left scratching my head...why would it? Eh whatever my stuff works now. Thanks poster!

Comment: Note about the implementation: `self::MY_CONST` is based on **[Late static bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)**, released in PHP **5.3.0** (implemented in git [Added support for Late Static Binding. (Dmitry, Etienne Kneuss)](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/166266df68db50c4d1119f2be265972c8d77f1af)). Core implementation is in `get_called_class()`. PHP <= 5.2.x gives error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC`.

Comment: Ok, works... but why? Mind expanding the answer to give more details?

Comment: FYI: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#114143

Answer (score 29):

**Since php 5.3:**

Use `static::MY_CONST`

---

**More details on `static`**

In this case [the keyword `static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#language.oop5.late-static-bindings.usage) is a reference to the actually called class.

This illustrates the difference between `static $var`, `static::$var` and `self::$var`:

```
class Base {
    const VALUE = 'base';

    static function testSelf() {
        // Output is always 'base', because `self::` is always class Base
        return self::VALUE;
    }

    static function testStatic() {
        // Output is variable: `static::` is a reference to the called class.
        return static::VALUE;
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    const VALUE = 'child';
}

echo Base::testStatic();  // output: base
echo Base::testSelf();    // output: base

echo Child::testStatic(); // output: child
echo Child::testSelf();   // output: base
```

Also note that the keyword `static` has 2 quite different meanings:

```
class StaticDemo {
    static function demo() {
        // Type 1: `static` defines a static variable.
        static $Var = 'bar';

        // Type 2: `static::` is a reference to the called class.
        return static::VALUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: great explanation

Comment: Is it behaving the same when using static calls to static methods vs instanciating and calling object methods however? The "static" keyword in front of each method is concerning

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper there's no difference beterrn `Child::testStatic()` and `$child::testStatic()`. Though also `$child->testStatic()` works, you should stick to `::` for static methods - using `->` will throw a notice, and can be confusing for other developers

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
$c = get_class( $this );
echo $c::MY_CONST;
```

Do this

```
$c = get_class( $this );
echo constant($c . '::MY_CONST');
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with const as it prints "yonderyonder" (that's the thing about constants, they don't change), but it works fine with var:

```
<?php
class MyClass {

     var $MY_CONST = "yonder";

     public function __construct() {

     echo $this->MY_CONST;
     }
}

class ChildClass extends MyClass {

     var $MY_CONST = "bar";
}

$x = new ChildClass(); // prints 'bar'
$y = new MyClass(); // prints 'yonder'

?>
```

Comment: 2015 - we don't need var

Comment: Yeah, this response was written 5 years ago, where it was still a thing!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access constants, properties, methods of classes or objects you can use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), it provides much more details about structure of the object.
example:

```
class MainClass
{
    const name = 'Primary';

    public $foo = 'Foo Variable';
}
class ExtendedClass extends MainClass
{
    const name = 'Extended';
}

/**
 * From Class Name
 */

//get reflection of main class
$mainReflection = new ReflectionClass('MainClass');

if($mainReflection->hasConstant('name'))
    var_dump($mainReflection->getConstant('name'));//Primary

//get reflection of extended class
$extendedReflection = new ReflectionClass('ExtendedClass');

if($extendedReflection->hasConstant('name'))
    var_dump($extendedReflection->getConstant('name'));//Extended

/**
 * From Objects
 */
$main = new MainClass();
$extended = new ExtendedClass();

//get reflection of main class
$mainReflection = new ReflectionObject($main);

if($mainReflection->hasConstant('name'))
    var_dump($mainReflection->getConstant('name'));//Primary

//get reflection of extended class
$extendedReflection = new ReflectionObject($extended);

if($extendedReflection->hasConstant('name'))
    var_dump($extendedReflection->getConstant('name'));//Extended
```