# PHP: How can I access a children class function from parent class variable?

Tags: php, class, oop

I am trying to do something, and I obviously seem to be missing something. I am new to this thing sorry.

```
class PARENT_API {
    function __construct() {

    }
}
$api = new PARENT_API();

class common extends PARENT_API {
    function foo(){
        return 'Test!';
    }
}
```

Why I can't just do this?

```
echo $api->common->foo();
```

I am just trying to organize large code into classes, can't I do that, what I am missing?

Comment: If a parent needs to access a child function you're doing OOP wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I seen plugins doing it. $parent->childclass->function() or variable. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: This is not how you do OOP in php (or any other language I know of). Please read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: `childclass` is a property called childclass.. it's not actually a child. `PARENT_API` should not be aware of, nor depend on, `common` in any way.

Comment: Aha sorry I got it wrong then =( so there's no way to avoid calling the child class to get the foo()?

Comment: No, and it wouldn't make sense anyway. Are you maybe mixing up parent and child class?

Comment: I think you're confusing child class and member variable. `$api->common->foo()` works if there is a member variable in `$api` called `$common` that has a class function called `foo()`. But that's not what you're declaring here.

Comment: Even if Mike B is right that your requirement is wrong concept, you might find interesting to read about related topic – [Late Static Bindings implementation in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). See also example in SO question [How to access constant defined in child class from parent class functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430348/how-to-access-constant-defined-in-child-class-from-parent-class-functions/13861732#13861732)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing dependencies and extensibility...

**Dependency**: A parent object may need a child object to execute some operations under the cover for it. It also allows you to switch easily the children object and change the way the parent will operate.

**Extensibility**: A children class may inherit from a parent class. It can say that BClass is also an AClass and can do the exact same thing but slightly differently. Only BClass can assess AClass because BClass is also an AClass, but the reverse is not true!

Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `foo()` method like this

```
$api_1 = new common();
$api_1->foo();
```

> I seen plugins doing it. $parent->childclass->function() or variable.
>   Am I overlooking something?

I really doubt that. I don't think Parent can inherit Child.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, your child class function is this:

```
class common extends PARENT_API {
    function foo(){
        echo 'Test!';
    }
}
```

But you are then calling it like this:

```
echo $api->common->foo();
```

Two `echo`’s? Change the class function to this so output is returned:

```
class common extends PARENT_API {
    function foo(){
        return 'Test!';
    }
}
```

Also, it should be called as:

```
$api_common = new common();
echo $api_common->foo();
```

**EDIT** When you do a `class common extends PARENT_API` you are creating a new `common` class.  So you cannot call `PARENT_API` and then expect it to be magically extended.  You need to call `common`.

Comment: So there's no way to get the foo() without calling the child class new Child() ?